# PHP5 Syntax Error in UrlEncoded string, missing a correct ' \ ' character

Tags: php, arrays, url, replace

Dear folks, in order to remove some really crazy `/%A/%E\%FD` occuring in the urls by freaking translation software, i am trying to seed some order into the url chaos:

```
$search   = array(' ',  ',',  '/',  '\',  'amp%3B',  '+',  '--',  '[',  ']');
$replace  = array('-',  '' ,  '' ,  '',   ''       ,  '' ,  '-' ,  '' ,  '' );
```

Worked fine untill I added the '\' apparently thats a special char?!

**Q1. First question: ERROR `'\'`**  How to I capture a single (one) `\`  ?

**Q2. Neigher `&` or `amp%3B` or `&amp;` capture and ampercant?** what to do capture that from url?

**Q3. Enhancement Sugestions?** that I have forgotten to make this really timeless?
In other words: are there any other special chars in url that can break the logic like the '/' which represents folder structures that I happily found out myself and removed, not allowed it to be in the url.

Comment: @experimentX, for the love of experiment: `[Mon Mar 28 08:25:17 2011] [error] [client 66.249.67.20] File does not exist: /var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/webpage-\xec\x8b\xa0\xeb\x85\x84-\xec\xb9\xb4\xeb\x93\x9c-\xed\x81\xac\xeb\xa6\xac\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\xa7\x88\xec\x8a\xa4-\xec\xb9\xb4\xeb\x93\x9c `

Comment: `\ ` is the escape character. You can even see in SO syntax highlighter that it breaks your string.

Comment: another failed request, I just want to UNallow any of these kinds of urls hitting my site: `\xec\x9e\x90\xec\x8b\xa0\xec\x9d\x98-\xeb\x94\x94\xec\x9e\x90\xec\x9d\xb8\xec\x9d\x84\xed\x95\x98\xeb\x8b\xa4`

Comment: @Felix, thanks but I cannot see what you mean by '':  please place as anser.   The worst thing what can happen is 1 upvote from me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help you??

```
$string = '/var/www/vhosts/site.com/httpdocs/webpage-\xec\x8b\xa0\xeb\x85\x84-\xec\xb9\xb4\xeb\x93\x9c-\xed\x81\xac\xeb\xa6\xac\xec\x8a\xa4\xeb\xa7\x88\xec\x8a\xa4-\xec\xb9\xb4\xeb\x93    \x9c';

$search   = array(' ',  ',',  '/',  '\\',  'amp%3B',  '+',  '--',  '[',  ']');

$replace  = array('-',  '' ,  '' ,  '',   ''       ,  '' ,  '-' ,  '' ,  '' );

$count=0;
foreach($search as $sch)
{
    $string =  str_replace($sch, $replace[$count], $string);
    $count++;
}

echo $string;
```

Comment: Thanks @experimentX that exactly what I was looking for. I wish you a pleasant day! Greetings with a Sunrise from Holland

Answer (score 2):

Ans 1 :  use `'\\'`  instead of `'\'`

`'\'` is the escape character. So need to use `'\\'`

Answer (score 2):

Q1: escape the `\` by using another `\` so it would be `\\`

Answer (score 1):

Try `'\\'` for `\` -- backslash is an escape character that is used to generate e.g. `\n` newline, `\r` carriage return, and so forth.

Many languages will do very little escaping in `''` single-quote strings, but typically still support

```
' embedded \' single quote'
```

so they also need to support

```
'embedded \\ backslash'
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `'\\'` to leave messages in the code